# Triggering cron by calling wp-cron.php on the command line rather than with wget?

Tags: wp-cron

Can you just trigger `wp-cron.php` using for example `$ php /path/to/wordpress/wp-cron.php` rather than going through the wget method using for example `wget -q -O - http://example.com/wp-cron.php>/dev/null 2>&1`?

Comment: Question is: Why would you want/need to do it that way?

Comment: @leymannx for many reasons, maybe your system does not have wget? Cron type of tasks should not require web layer anyway and you should be able to run cron even without the whole site being up.

Answer (score 9):

Looking at the file documentation inside `wp-cron.php` it seems it's absolutely possible to just call `$ php wp-cron.php`:

> ```
> /**
>  * A pseudo-CRON daemon for scheduling WordPress tasks
>  *
>  * WP Cron is triggered when the site receives a visit. In the scenario
>  * where a site may not receive enough visits to execute scheduled tasks
>  * in a timely manner, this file can be called directly or via a server
>  * CRON daemon for X number of times.
>  *
>  * Defining DISABLE_WP_CRON as true and calling this file directly are
>  * mutually exclusive and the latter does not rely on the former to work.
>  *
>  * The HTTP request to this file will not slow down the visitor who happens to
>  * visit when the cron job is needed to run.
>  *
>  * @package WordPress
>  */
> ```

---

What else you can do on the command line, is to use [wp-cli](https://wp-cli.org) for that.

```
$ cd /path/to/wordpress
$ wp cron event run --due-now
```

To force-trigger one single cron independent from its set schedule run:

```
$ wp cron event run my_custom_cron_event
```

Or as a one-liner to be used in a crontab to run every full hour + 15 minutes (2:15 pm, 3:15pm, 4:15pm etc.):

```
15 * * * * cd /path/to/wordpress && wp cron event run --due-now > /dev/null 2>&1
```

Comment: Is there a benefit to using `curl` versus the `wp` cli tool?

Comment: @BarryChapman – Curl basically is just another page request. So it may potentially slow the site down a bit when the cron runs.

Comment: @BarryChapman I guess that any code that depends on $_SERVER or other session variables will not like being called from the command line. Other than that you should be fine

Comment: It is worth to mention, that wp-cli runs cron via HTTP. It is not definitely same as calling wp-cron from CLI PHP, because for example max_execution_time can affect the cron runs. If you have issues with timeouting cron tasks, I'd recommend to call the wp-cron.php directly, without involving wp-cli.

Comment: @GaborGarami wp-cli does an http request out of the command line?? 

Comment: Based on my testings, yes.

Answer (score 7):

Yes, it's possible to trigger cron runs with just `$ php /path/to/wordpress/wp-cron.php`.

Alternatively you can use `curl`:

```
*/10 * * * * curl http://example.com/wp-cron.php > /dev/null 2>&1
```

And you can add the following line to your `wp-config.php` to disable crons being run from HTTP requests:

```
define('DISABLE_WP_CRON', true);
```

Comment: If you are using curl that's still an HTTP request so probably not a good idea to DISABLE_WP_CRON?

Comment: @Bananaapple – By calling wp-cron.php directly you circumvent that. But at the same time `DISABLE_WP_CRON` prevents that cron is triggered from visitors browsing any page of your site. See https://kinsta.com/knowledgebase/disable-wp-cron/ and in the file comments in my answer above `Defining DISABLE_WP_CRON as true and calling this file directly are mutually exclusive and the latter does not rely on the former to work`.