# Cronjob returns a lot of REMOTE_ADDR, SERVER_PORT, SERVER_NAME, etc errors

Tags: cron

I wrote a **cron script** and included at the top

```
require_once('/home/cli6951n3/domains/mydomain.com/public_html/wp-load.php');
```

In `wp-config.php` I added this line:

```
define('DISABLE_WP_CRON', true);
```

As result I get a huge amount of **errors**. See text below. A lot plugins and the Themes are mentioned in the error reports. 
**How can I solve this?**

> PHP Notice:  Undefined index: SERVER_PORT in
>   /home/cli6951n3/domains/mydomain.com/public_html/wp-content/plugins/wp-fastest-cache/wpFastestCache.php
>   on line 1536
>
> Notice: Undefined index: SERVER_PORT in
>   /home/cli6951n3/domains/mydomain.com/public_html/wp-content/plugins/wp-fastest-cache/wpFastestCache.php
>   on line 1536 PHP Notice:  Undefined index: SERVER_NAME in
>   /home/cli6951n3/domains/mydomain.com/public_html/wp-content/plugins/wp-fastest-cache/wpFastestCache.php
>   on line 1537
>
> Notice: Undefined index: SERVER_NAME in
>   /home/cli6951n3/domains/mydomain.com/public_html/wp-content/plugins/wp-fastest-cache/wpFastestCache.php
>   on line 1537 PHP Notice:  Undefined index: SERVER_PORT in
>   /home/cli6951n3/domains/mydomain.com/public_html/wp-content/plugins/wp-fastest-cache/wpFastestCache.php
>   on line 1537
>
> Notice: Undefined index: SERVER_PORT in
>   /home/cli6951n3/domains/mydomain.com/public_html/wp-content/plugins/wp-fastest-cache/wpFastestCache.php
>   on line 1537 PHP Notice:  Undefined index: HTTP_HOST in
>   /home/cli6951n3/domains/mydomain.com/public_html/wp-content/plugins/wp-fastest-cache/inc/cache.php
>   on line 177
>
> Notice: Undefined index: HTTP_HOST in
>   /home/cli6951n3/domains/mydomain.com/public_html/wp-content/plugins/wp-fastest-cache/inc/cache.php
>   on line 177 PHP Notice:  Undefined index: HTTP_HOST in
>   /home/cli6951n3/domains/mydomain.com/public_html/wp-content/plugins/minimal-coming-soon-maintenance-mode/framework/public/init.php
>   on line 38
>
> Notice: Undefined index: HTTP_HOST in
>   /home/cli6951n3/domains/mydomain.com/public_html/wp-content/plugins/minimal-coming-soon-maintenance-mode/framework/public/init.php
>   on line 38 PHP Warning:  Cannot modify header information - headers
>   already sent by (output started at
>   /home/cli6951n3/domains/mydomain.com/public_html/wp-content/plugins/rdp-plugin/rdp-plugin.php:1)
>   in
>   /home/cli6951n3/domains/mydomain.com/public_html/wp-content/themes/Avada-Child-Theme/functions.php
>   on line 13
>
> Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by
>   (output started at
>   /home/cli6951n3/domains/mydomain.com/public_html/wp-content/plugins/rdp-plugin/rdp-plugin.php:1)
>   in
>   /home/cli6951n3/domains/mydomain.com/public_html/wp-content/themes/Avada-Child-Theme/functions.php
>   on line 13 PHP Notice:  Undefined index: REMOTE_ADDR in
>   /home/cli6951n3/domains/mydomain.com/public_html/wp-content/themes/Avada/includes/avadaredux/avadaredux-framework/AvadaReduxCore/inc/class.avadaredux_helpers.php
>   on line 69
>
> Notice: Undefined index: REMOTE_ADDR in
>   /home/cli6951n3/domains/mydomain.com/public_html/wp-content/themes/Avada/includes/avadaredux/avadaredux-framework/AvadaReduxCore/inc/class.avadaredux_helpers.php
>   on line 69 PHP Notice:  Undefined index: REMOTE_ADDR in
>   /home/cli6951n3/domains/mydomain.com/public_html/wp-content/themes/Avada/includes/avadaredux/avadaredux-framework/AvadaReduxCore/inc/class.avadaredux_helpers.php
>   on line 69
>
> Notice: Undefined index: REMOTE_ADDR in
>   /home/cli6951n3/domains/mydomain.com/public_html/wp-content/themes/Avada/includes/avadaredux/avadaredux-framework/AvadaReduxCore/inc/class.avadaredux_helpers.php
>   on line 69 PHP Notice:  Undefined index: REMOTE_ADDR in
>   /home/cli6951n3/domains/mydomain.com/public_html/wp-content/themes/Avada/includes/avadaredux/avadaredux-framework/AvadaReduxCore/inc/class.avadaredux_helpers.php
>   on line 69

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? It's not clear from the question.

Comment: Does the cron script call the php executable directly?

Comment: I try to solve these issues. The cron script is call the exectuble directly from the server.

Comment: Please [edit your question](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/posts/245745/edit) to include the content of your `cron` script.

Comment: Those sound likes indexes in the `$_SERVER` array, which don't exist when run from a command line script, since those values are obtained from HTTP headers. You should look at creating your cron script in WordPress like here http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/49927/add-action-to-wp-cron and then scheduling like http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/199725/triggering-wp-cron-by-cronjab-directly-rather-than-with-wget

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're getting `Undefined index` errors because you're loading the files directly and not rendered through the server. The server typically populates those values and it's actually more secure to run with less elevated privileges (through an `HTTP` request).

Throw your manual cron to a `curl` or `wget` -- whichever you have installed on your server.

```
curl -s -H "User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64)" http://YourWebsiteURL.com/wp-cron.php?doing_wp_cron
```

OR

```
wget -O /dev/null http://www.YourWebsiteURL.com/wp-cron.php?doing_wp_cron > /dev/null 2>&1
```

This should trigger your `cron` and with `www` privileges instead of server `root` access.

Comment: Thanks for the idea how to solve it, With wget it runs well. Have a nice day.